# Why does changing the number of hidden neurons in this network show no effect on efficiency?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network

I have just coded the neural network from this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkwX7FkLfug

Although not really needed, the source code is available here
http://inkdrop.net/dave/docs/neural-net-tutorial.cpp

I changed the input data code slightly, so now my program tests if points will be above or below a line. This function works. It prints the exact same input/target file, but with values between 0 and 20 for X and Y coordinates, and the output value is calculated as 0 or 1 based on if this point lies above the line Y = 2x+4. The input file is generated and is accurate.

I have run some tests, and found interesting results.  Running the program with a 2 4 1 (2 input neurons, 4 hidden, 1 output) topology and 2000 input values yields an initial error of 9.164...E61
on pass 1. On pass 2000, the error is reduced to -2.086...E53, still fairly inaccurate...

Now, let's increase the input size to 10000. Obviously, this should increase the accuracy of the program as it has more to learn off of. And it does, the error is now reduced to -5.602...E18, and I can see that it's output values are very accurate.

Here is where the problem comes in. Unless I am wrong, I thought that the number of hidden neurons in a network is the thing that increases it's efficiency. I've changed the topology to 2 50 1, and kept the input size at 2000. But this leads to the same results as before!! Why is this? Shouldn't increasing the number of hidden neurons reduce the error with the same input size?

UPDATE: I have just tried increasing the number of layers of hidden neurons, by using a topography of 2 4 4 4 4 4 1. This has shown no effect on the data

Comment: With an error that's limited to 1.0 per validation sample, how do you manage to get a 1E61 error?! I's suspect that logic is wrong, which means it might not be an architecture issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when trying to build a neural model, you start with small number of neurons. There are exceptions like Deepnets or Reservoir computing.
You can increase the number of neurons, however, providing too many enlarges the search space so much, you might not have enought data to train,or the net becomes more of memory than rule model, and of course you need more iterations to train it.
I would look at other ways to improve the net, look at inputs, network type, transfer functions.

Comment: But why would this result in absolutely no change in data? Surely changing the number of hidden layers from 1 to 5 would cause some efficiency increase, without compromising memory or using too much search space?

Comment: You mean the test results give out the exact same sequence?

Comment: Yes, changing the number of neurons results in the same output file

Comment: Hmm,this happened to me to, honestly did not dig deeper. My bet is the learning algorithm used can affect this, if you can, change it, there are many out there. Remember each neuron slices the space into two subspaces and it might not matter if you do it in 4 layers or just 2. What are you trying to model ?

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the number of layers or perceptrons doesn't (shouldn't) necessarily have a direct impact on the output because the neural network is being trained to respond to certain stimuli. Take the most basic neural network: one with a single perceptron which returns the input value (this is maximum fitness). It should be obvious that ading more layers or perceptrons doesn't improve the performance of this network by any measure.

Typically, layers are added to handle non-linearities in the input data (if the data was linear, there is probably an easier solution than neural networks for processing your data). If you have a sufficient number of layers to represent nonlinearities in the problem's space then increasing the number of layers should have little effect on the output.

Source: just finished a semester project on neural networks and had the same questions, I can add specific sources once I dig them back up if you'd like.

Comment: What would be an example of a non linearity? Right now I only have two inputs but I'd like to scale that up, I just don't know what it would entail

Comment: The number of inputs doesn't change how linear a problem is. The easiest way to think of linearity is: can I come up with a single equation (even if it is really complicated) that computes every solution in this space? If so, the space is linear. Take XOR for example: you canniit write an equation on binary variables A and B which produces the XOR operation. The neural network equivalent is: you cannot design a single-layer network which performs the XOR operation. Conversely, the equation A*B yields the AND operator: thus AND is linear,and XOR is non-linear.

Comment: To get a mental picture of linearity: draw any line you want on a plot. If you can come up with an equation that produces that same line then your equation is linear (not to be confused with "straight lines" which are linear by definition, but not all linear lines are straight).

Comment: This is strange, because the first iteration of my program was a 2 4 1 net that calculated XOR

Comment: Yes, that network has two layers, thus it can compute XOR.